# Decoding [] bytes i get only characters �����

Tags: java, android-studio, arduino, inputstream, decoding

I'm trying to decode a `[]byte` from an Arduino BT, I got the connection perfectly, the problem is when I try to decode the array. all that I get is this character � (the same number of bytes sent) I think that the problem is on the decoding. I try with ASCII charset but still the same problem. I'm using Android Studio and set to UTF-8 format.

Could someone tell me what is happening please?

OutputStream:

```js
public void write(byte[] bytes) {

            String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
```

InputStream:

```js
 public void run (){
            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytes;

            while(true){
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    String incomingMessage = new String (buffer,0,bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
                    Log.d(TAG,"InputStream: " + incomingMessage);


                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("El mensaje", incomingMessage);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Mensaje enviado a la main actv " + incomingMessage);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast (incomingMessageIntent);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Error leyendo Imputstream"  +e.getMessage());

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

[Logcat to see the character that I receive:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhxV.png)

Comment: is the byte array passed from the arduino supposed to be readable?

Comment: I think that yes, im using Serial.write from arduino, i'd tried Serial.write(72), Serial.write('H') and always get the same character  �

Comment: Try sending from the Arduino Serial.print("1234ABCD\r\n");

Answer (score 0):

From the Arduino side you should use char as sending format.

`Serial.write`  Writes binary data to the serial port. This data is sent as a byte or series of bytes

So simply try to decode

```
Serial.print("1234ABCD\r\n");
```

Not knowing the commands on Android I guess bytes in Arduino speak is char and not binary data. And always post all code used!

Comment: I solved the problem!, The  UART of BT was seted at 38400 baud. i chaged it to 9600 and everithing its ok!!!! daaaaaaaaaaaaaam! a weeek to solve that!!!! :D . Thank you very much for the response!!.